# Appending leading zeroes to a given value

Tags: python

I have various inputs like below,i need to make any given digit as four letter and append leading zeroes to make it four digit
and add a "00.00" at the front,can any suggest how to do this?

```
INPUT:-

val = int(95)
val = int(115)
val = int(5)


EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

00.00.0095
00.00.0115
00.00.0005
```

Comment: how to append "00.00" ?

Comment: if it fixed, just append a literal

Comment: Well, since `00.00.0095` is no longer an int or any other type of number I can think of, why not just use a string and concatenate?

Comment: `print '00.00.{0:04d}'.format(val)` as per the linked to duplicate answers

Comment: That is not an int...also thats not even a valid float

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this, assuming 00.00 is always constant.

```
print(["00.00.{:>04d}".format(v) for v in [95, 115, 5]])
# ['00.00.0095', '00.00.0115', '00.00.0005']
```